# Selenium-Get list index number based on text match

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Automation scenario is to get all the links in weblist & then get this arraylist content outside loop and then get the index number dynamically based on the url hit.

```
String values="";
List<WebElement> url_link = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".anomaly>a"));
for ( WebElement we: url_link) { 

    String temp = values;
    values = temp + we.getText();
}
System.out.println("Text "+values);
int ind=values.indexOf("www.test.com");

System.out.println("Index "+ind);
```

The above code returns me a weird index number of 74.

The url_link output contents are:

```
wwww.hatch.com
wwww.tist.com
wwww.helix.com
wwww.patching.com
wwww.seyh.com
wwww.test.com
wwww.toast.com
wwww.telling.com
wwww.uity.com
```

so based upon the expected result i am expecting the index number to be 5.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `values` is a variable of type `String`, it's not a `List`. So when you do `values = temp + we.getText();`, you are basically appending all the links in a single `String`. So the output will actually be this:

```
wwww.hatch.comwwww.tist.comwwww.helix.comwwww.patching.comwwww.seyh.comwwww.test.comwwww.toast.comwwww.telling.comwwww.uity.com
```

The index of `www.test.com` is 74 in this string. You should be adding these links in an `ArrayList` and then find the index of the link you want to search.

Something like this should work:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> url_link = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".anomaly>a"));
for ( WebElement we: url_link) { 

    values.add(we.getText());
}

int ind = values.indexOf("www.test.com");

System.out.println("Index "+ind);
```